# Microsoft Graph SendMail returns ErrorInternalServerError

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing a program to send internal emails in VB.Net using the official Microsoft Graph package. At first I got it to send calendar invites and that worked fine for months, but when I tried to add the ability to send emails I keep getting an Internal Server Error.

From looking at other times people have got this error from Graph, it appears to be when a malformed request is sent or when values that don't quite make sense are given. I'm using the constructors from the package and using basically the same construction method as every example online, so the structure of the request can't be wrong, and the only fields that I'm using just take text and don't do anything with it, so I don't think that can be the issue either.

I have the correct permissions in Azure:  [Screenshot of permissions in Azure, including Mail.Send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hO0.png)

Here's my code for constructing the email:

```
Function DefineImportantEmail(Locations As String, Recipients As List(Of (String, String))) As Message
    Dim title = "IMPORTANT OUTAGE NOTIFICATION"
    Dim message = "Outage at " & Locations

    Dim RecipientList = New List(Of Recipient)
    For Each recipient In Recipients
        RecipientList.Add(New Attendee With {
                .EmailAddress = New EmailAddress With {
                    .Address = recipient.Item1,
                    .Name = recipient.Item2
                },
                .Type = AttendeeType.Optional
            })
    Next

    Return New Message With {
        .Subject = title,
        .Body = New ItemBody With {
            .ContentType = BodyType.Text,
            .Content = message
        },
        .ToRecipients = RecipientList
    }
End Function
```

And here's the code I use to send the email:

```
Sub SendImportantEmail(Locations As String, Recipients As List(Of (String, String)))
    Dim SaveToSentItems = True
    Dim graphClient = GetGraphClient()
    Dim EventObject = DefineImportantEmail(Locations, Recipients)
    Dim request = graphClient.Users("xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com").SendMail(EventObject, SaveToSentItems).Request().PostAsync()
    request.Wait()
End Sub
```

The GetGraphClient function works for any other API endpoint I've tried, so I haven't included it. The censored user is from our organisation and is also the user I sent calendar invites from in the first version of this program.

Here's the full error message I get:

(Code: ErrorInternalServerError
Message: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
ClientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
)
---> Status Code: InternalServerError
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorInternalServerError
Message: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
ClientRequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: You're calling `DefineImportantEmail` with `StartTime` and `EndTime` but those are not defined in your sample. Are you creating an `Event` or `Message`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Sorry, that was caused by copying code from different versions. `StartTime` and `EndTime` were strings in the body of the email, but I removed them to isolate the issue, which still happens without them. I've edited my post to remove them.

Comment: Have you tried the same request on postman to isolate the problem being the payload sent by your app? You can do this by generating the access token and testing from Postman. Please share the inner error details with request id and timestamp.